# print an unknown length argument in linux assembly

Tags: linux, assembly

In linux assembly, we can write a string to the default output with system call `write`. But this system call needs the string length, but the argument doesn't have a fixed length over all the executions.

So, I know that we can calculate the length of the argument by browsing it and looking for the null byte. Although, I am looking for a simpler way to print an argument (or any string with unknown length) with Linux assembly.

So can anyone tell me the simplest way to print an unknown string length with Linux assembly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no Linux system calls that write an implicit-length string (C-style null-terminated) to a file descriptor.  So you have to just work out the length yourself before making a system call.

Linux is portable across many architectures, so I'll express the answer in portable assembly language, aka C:

```
int write_implicit_length_string(const char *str) {
    size_t size = strlen(str);
    return write(1, str, size);  // stdout is always fd 1
}
```

If you want to see the asm, [compile it with gcc](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g530,options:'-xc+-Wall+-Wextra+-pedantic+-std%3Dgnu99+-fverbose-asm+-O3+-march%3Dhaswell',source:'%23include+%3Cstring.h%3E%0A%23include+%3Cunistd.h%3E%0Aint+write_implicit_length_string(const+char*str)+%7B%0A++++size_t+size+%3D+strlen(str)%3B%0A++++return+write(1,+str,+size)%3B++//+stdout+is+always+fd+1%0A%7D%0A')),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,intel:!t,labels:!t),version:3) (although that will just show you a function call to strlen.  gcc -O3 doesn't inline code for strlen on x86).

As far as asm implementations of strlen, for x86-64 your best bet is an SSE2 loop that uses pcmpeqb / pmovmskb / test / jnz to find the first zero byte.  Obviously every ISA will have its own way of doing it, but the important point is that there's no way to have the kernel do it for you.

There are C standard library functions that print strings to stdio `FILE  *` (e.g. `fputs`) but not to unix file descriptors (libc just has wrappers for system calls).

Comment: Thanks bro. I tried to use printf in assembly, but in that case, I have to compile with `gcc` because compiling with `ld` won't let me use the C functions (it shows some kind of error when I try to execute).

Comment: @Sidahmed: that's correct, building with `gcc` is the best way to link libc.  You *can* still use libc from a "bare" assembly program (`_start` not `main`) with `gcc -nostartfiles`.  You will get a dynamic executable that way, or you can use `-static`.  This is a better choice than using `ld my.o -lc`, since you need extra options to get the ELF-interpreter field set correctly, etc. etc.

Comment: Thanks bro. Just this last dumb question (I want to confirm this by hearing it from an expert) : When I compile with gcc, the executable code won't change, but does the other parts (like the header of the file, or some extra infos) change in the executable file ??!!

Comment: @Sidahmed: gcc just runs `as` and `ld` with the correct options.  You can use `gcc -v my_file.S` to see it in action.  So yes, your asm still assembles the same.

Comment: Bro, you just gave some priceless informations, I wish I could do more than just giving you a thumb up. God bless you :)